# How to implement a share bottom sheet like in Google Photos

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to build the sharing functionality in my app with React Native. The requirement is quite like Google Photos.

[Google photos' sharing bottom sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBMNb.jpg)

This includes a customized section at the top to let the user input some information such as readonly/editable. The bottom section is the same as iOS/Android system sharing functionality.

Here is the library to build a bottom sheet:

https://github.com/nysamnang/react-native-raw-bottom-sheet.

However, it has no information about how to trigger the sharing channels.

Here is a library with sharing channels:

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share.

But it can only share with the predefined channels.

So my question is:

1. Can I reuse the system-built bottom sheet by iOS/Android and
   customize it? If so, how?
2. If I can't directly customize, is there a 3rd party library to mimic it? How can I integrate with iOS/Android to get the installed apps to share?

Answer (score 0):

Use [react-native-share](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-share), it has default implementation and also allows you to create custom UI

Comment: Unfortunately, it only supports very limited channel with IOS. SMS is the most important channel that we need, but it's not supported.

Comment: for sms, use linking with url=`sms:+19725551212?body=hello%20there`